# Laravel - Is there a way to optimize often used tasks?

Tags: laravel, optimization

For example, I have a lot of tasks, like let's say we have a list of user.
I need to provide Views and Functions for

- Displaying Users
- Editing a User
- Deleting a User
- Adding an User

Now I want to add Settings to my site, so again I need views and functions to

- Display all Settings
- Editing a Setting
- Deleting a setting
- Adding a setting

And so on, so you have a lot of models which require similar View and controllers. It's a bit repetitive.

Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: Not unless your modals have the same layout too :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is actually a pretty easy way to do this. Take a look at [Rousource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers). With a single artisan command you can generate a controller with all the methods you need. In your case, `php artisan make:controller UserController --resource` for example. Then, in your routes, you can just add `Route::resource('users', 'UserController');`. You may have to tweak these default methods of course, but I'll give you a good starting point and should save you a lot of work.

Comment: Thank you, will try it out.